# React app - IconMenu not expanded on Click event.

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, events, material-ui

I need help with react app and IconMenu from material-ui.
Studying many similar issues without results :(

Having following code, I want to trigger menu expand manually - I need it in tests framework to simulate clicking on submenu item.

```
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <IconMenu 
            iconButtonElement={<FlatButton style={{height: '100%'}
            }
            onClick={() => console.log('clicked!')}
            label={'FooLabel'}
            labelPosition='before'
            />}>
            <MenuItem primaryText="submenu" leftIcon={<SignOutIcon />} />
        </IconMenu>
    );
};
```

The problem is that, when I do click on menu item, the onClick event is triggered, but menu is not expanded at all:

demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqgXO.jpg

I was trying to send custom event by dispatchEvent function, but even onClick is not triggered.
Is something what i missed?

Comment: Can you show the code of your custom event ?

Comment: var evt = new CustomEvent(
        "click", 
        {
            detail: {
                time: new Date(),
            }
        }
    );
    panel.dispatchEvent(evt);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by using onClick you override the default behaviour, so you'll need to use IconMenu's `open` prop and tell it when you want it to be open (true) or closed (false).

You'll need to have some code in your component that toggles `open` between true and false. To do this, the component will need to be stateful instead of functional. If you haven't done this before, check out the react docs on [converting a function to a class](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class)

Try:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false
    };
  }

  _toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
      menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen
    });
  };

  _handleClick = () => {
    this._toggleOpen();
    // .. do your other on click stuff here
  }

  render(
    <IconMenu 
        iconButtonElement={<FlatButton style={{height: '100%'}
        }
        onClick={this._handleClick}
        label={'FooLabel'}
        labelPosition='before'
        open={this.state.menuOpen}
        />}>
        <MenuItem primaryText="submenu" leftIcon={<SignOutIcon />} />
    </IconMenu>
  );
}
```

so now we've got a state that the Menu component can update which will decide whether the menu should be open and which gets passed down into the open prop.